# Keras accuracy and loss keeps going up and down

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0, gradient-descent

I have a dataset of posts from Reddit and the subreddit they are from, and I am trying to write a model that tries to predict the subreddit of a post given its title.

This is a sample of my data:
[image]

This is how I preprocess my data:

```
title_tokenizer = Tokenizer()
title_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df.title)
max_sentence_len = len(df.title.max())
title_voc_size = len(title_tokenizer.word_index)

subreddit_tokenizer = Tokenizer()
subreddit_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df.subreddit)
subreddits_size = len(subreddit_tokenizer.word_index)

def preprocess(title, subreddit):
    title_sequence = title_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([title.numpy().decode("utf-8")])
    title_padded = pad_sequences(title_sequence, max_sentence_len)[0]

    subreddit_sequence = subreddit_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([subreddit.numpy().decode("utf-8")])
    subreddit_categorical_value = keras.utils.to_categorical(subreddit_sequence[0][0], subreddits_size + 1)
    return title_padded, subreddit_categorical_value

def set_shape_func(title, subreddit):
    title.set_shape(max_sentence_len)
    subreddit.set_shape(subreddits_size + 1)
    return title, subreddit

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.title, df.subreddit))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: tf.py_function(preprocess, [x, y], [tf.int64, tf.int64]))
dataset = dataset.map(set_shape_func)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(50)
dataset = dataset.repeat(None)
dataset = dataset.batch(128).prefetch(1)
```

and this is the code for the model and its training:

```
epochs = 500
steps_per_epoch = 20
lr = 0.015
inputs = keras.Input(max_sentence_len)

x = keras.layers.Embedding(title_voc_size+1, 100)(inputs)
x = keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(256, return_sequences=True))(x)
x = keras.layers.LSTM(128)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(1/3)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(subreddits_size + 1, activation='softmax')(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(keras.optimizers.SGD(lr), 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch)

loss, acc = model.evaluate(dataset, steps=epochs*steps_per_epoch)

model.save('models/{}-loss-{}-acc-{}-epochs-{}-steps-{}-lr-subreddit-prediction.model'.format(loss, acc, epochs, steps_per_epoch, lr))
```

And for some reason, the accuracy and loss keep fluctuating, you can see it in this graph:
(blue is loss and orange is accuracy)
[image]

what can I do to make my loss and accuracy more consistent and get better results?

Comment: What happens if you decrease the learning rate, and/or increase the number of steps in an epoch?

Comment: @BartoszKP The same thing, I tried to lower the learning rates and to increase epochs to 500 and I get the same result

Comment: Can you show results for `lr = 0.005` and for `steps_per_epoch = 100` (and for both)?

Comment: @BartoszKP Trained the model for 50 epochs on the parameters that you requested, the evaluation showed `loss: 4.4615 - acc: 0.0180`, if you want I can test the parameters alone (not both of them together) but due to the poor performance of the model, I'm not sure how sufficient would it be.

Comment: But what was the trend? Were the fluctuations smaller or bigger? The same? If the same, how the same? :-)